# How to check if document with certain fields already exists in the MongoDB database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I'm trying to check whether a document with certain fields already exist in the database.

I have a player object and I wanna make sure that there isn't another object with the same name and surname already in the database. I also want to check that the team name does not already occur.

The code below does not work because the code in the callback functions get executed after the if statement below them where the decision is made whether the data should be saved in the database based on the value of two variables that are supposed to get altered in the callback function if the certain condition is met.

However, those variables are altered after that if statement thus my code does not work.

The question is. How do I make the callback function execute when I want it to. Or is there a better way to do this kind of validation?

This is my code:

```
let team_exists = false;
let players_exist = false;

Team.count({name: team.name}, function(err, count){
    if (count>0){
        team_exists = true;
    }
});

players.forEach((function(player){
    Player.count({name: player.name, surname: player.surname}, function(err, count){
        if (count>0){
            players_exist = true;
        }
    })
}))

if(!team_exists && !players_exist){
    Player.insertMany(players, function(err){
        if(err){
            cosole.log(err);
        }
    })

    team.save(function(err){});
}
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of issues !! If `players` is an array when you iterate over it let's say player1 already exists in DB then `players_exist : true` atlas if playerN doesn't exists in DB then `players_exist : false` that case your query would write all players irrespective whether they already exist or not (Basically you code will only work if last player in players array doesn't exist)

Comment: How is your each player in players array related to team?? when you say you don't want Team name to be duplicated !! I don't see anywhere Team name is being inserted  (Is that inside each player's record)..

Comment: The value of players_exist is set to false by default. If player1 exists in the database it's changed to true but otherwise it stays as it is.Meaning if player2 is not in the database the variable will not be changed to false.This way if any player is in the database the end result will be true.

Comment: No, the team name is not related to players. It's another object that also should not be duplicated.

Comment: I don't know whether you get what I'm saying !! you're executing `insertMany` on a list of players then how could a single value `players_exist` decide player exists or not..

Comment: So you just wanted to check incoming team name already exists in `Team` collection or not, if not exists then add unique players to `player` collection ??

Comment: If only one of players in the array already exist none of them should be inserted in the database.

Comment: I wanted to add team to Team collection and players to Player collection only if team name is not a duplicate and none of the players in array are already in the Player collection.

Comment: Ok now your code makes sense, usually it wouldn't be the case (Do not add any user if one already exists) So I've got confused..

Comment: So is there any way I can make this code execute in correct order?

Comment: Yes you could do that, myself/someone will provide an answer..

Answer (score 1):

There is a mongodb operator **$exists** to check if a field exists in a document.

Usage

The following examples uses a collection named records with the following documents

```
{ a: 5, b: 5, c: null }
{ a: 3, b: 7, c: 8 }
{ a: 9, c: 9 }
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
{ a: 2, c: 5 }
{ a: 3, b: 2 }
```

The following can be used to check all the documents where b does not exist

> b : { $exists: false }:

The results consist of those documents that do not contain the field b:

```
{ a: 9, c: 9 }
{ a: 2, c: 5 }
```

In your case, check if a document aleready exists in the collection using the above mentioned query. Then you can insert documents conditionally after the results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Once possible solution is to place conditional code inside the callback.  This would allow you to process this without needing the booleans at all

Building an `$or` predicate from the players list allows you to check players_exist with a single query to the database instead of a query per player.

```
Team.count({name: team.name}, function(err, count){
    if (count == 0){
        let playerquery = [];
        players.forEach(function(player){ 
           playerquery.push({ name: player.name, 
                              surname: player.surname}); 
        })
        Player.count({$or:playerquery}, function(err, count){
            if (count == 0){
                Player.insertMany(players, function(err){
                        if(err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                })
                team.save(function(err){});
            }
        })
   }
})
```